# Firebase and AngularJS code not being reached

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I am trying to retrieve some data from a Firebase database like so:

```
usersRef.child(authData.facebook.id).on("value", function(snapshot) {
    console.log("Username" + snapshot.val().displayName);
  });
```

The code is almost exactly out of the firebase documentation but for some reason the console.log is never reached (I would like to eventually save the javascript object that is returned from the firebase call as well)

I am at a loss, I have already checked that authData.facebook.id is returning a valid child as I have an update statement that saves the data to the firebase db right before that.

Comment: I know you said you already checked but what exactly is authData.facebook.id evaluating to?

Comment: Evaluates to 1612774105652760 which is just a unique identifier given when authenitcating through facebook using firebases service. I use the facebook.id as the unique key for each user in the tree. So users/1612774105652760/...

Comment: This snippet is unlikely to be the problem, given that it's one of the most basic Firebase operations: `on("value"`. Please provide a minimal, complete piece of code that reproduces the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks but I found the issue thanks to Chris below. The user did not have the correct permissions. Or rather the uid being used was not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried attaching an error handler? If something is failing to occur, the error handler might be triggered with information regarding it:

```
usersRef.child(authData.facebook.id).on("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log("Username" + snapshot.val().displayName);
}, function(errorObject) {
  console.log("Error: ", errorObject);
});
```

Another thing to try is listening to the `child_added` event instead of the `value` event, to see if you're getting any data that way:

```
usersRef.child(authData.facebook.id).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  console.log("Username" + snapshot.val().displayName);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Chris! I am still learning JS so am missing a lot of things like that. The error function returned that the user did not have permission to access that data which makes sense because in my security file in firebase I made it so each uid needs to match to be able to write to that user node (obviously) but I have been using the uid from the facebook login as the users id in the tree.. Should be an easy fix.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!